# Problem with adding a special github project (mdict-java) to android studio project

Tags: github, mdd

there is a library to work with mdx and mdd files named [mdict-java](https://github.com/KnIfER/mdict-java) , but I didn't understand how it should be added to the Android Studio project. Apparently it is not a gradle project. I tried to make the library in android studio, but it didn't work.